# How to show only word and pdf documents using advance search webpart?

Tags: search-results, search-scope

I have document management site and want to show only word and pdf documents using advance search web part. currently it is showing ".aspx" pages in that search also.

Answer (score 2):

Change the default filter for the Search Results Web part to exclude Web pages. There are a number of ways to do this. You can try things like adding "AND NOT FileExtension:ASPX" to the query.